# How do I start a HealthKit workout on an iPhone?

Tags: ios, healthkit, watchos

I am writing an iPhone + Apple Watch app that can track workouts. The problem I am having is I find zero documention on how to manage the workout on the iPhone side.

This is the official documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/workouts_and_activity_rings/running_workout_sessions

it states:

> Coordinate with the Companion App
>
> If the watchOS app has an iOS companion, be sure to keep both apps in
> sync. This is particularly important if the user can start workouts on
> either device.
>
> If the user starts the workout in your watchOS app, and then tries to
> end it in the iOS companion, the iOS app should instruct the user to
> end the workout in your watchOS app. Otherwise, Apple Watch workout
> continues to run, which can lead to accidentally saving invalid data
> to the HealthKit store.
>
> If the user starts a workout in the iOS companion, and then opens your
> watchOS app, the watchOS app should automatically start a workout
> session for the workout in progress. If you save the workout in the
> watchOS app, you can incorporate data from the iOS workout. For
> example, you should set the workout’s startDate to the iOS workout’s
> start. Also, if your app calculates its own calories, you can
> retroactively give credit for the calories burned before the workout
> session began.
>
> If the user doesn’t start and stop a workout session in your watchOS
> app, don’t try to retroactively create a workout session on Apple
> Watch.

The only problem is there is zero documentation on how to do this.

So let's say I use `HKWorkoutBuilder` on iOS. How do I go from that to the `HKLiveWorkoutBuilder` and merge that data?